# Selenium Select .getOptions .selectBy.... not working

Tags: javascript, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

Like the title says the I cant get the Select functions to work on a page im working with.  Here is the Dom `

```
<div id="ember3366" class="ember-view">
<div class="row m-b-1">
<!---->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 m-b-1">
<label>Category</label>
<select class="form-control">
<option value="All">
<option value="Spirits">Spirits</option>
<option value="Wine">Wine</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And here is the code I have written

```
public void selectCategory(String text) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(category);
    Select sel = new Select(element);
    sel.selectByVisibleText(text);
}
```

Nothing gets selected.... when you run a console print out of .getOptions you get this back

[[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (c33ce4eedeef26cc3921b3e439811cf5)]  -> tag name: option], [[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (c33ce4eedeef26cc3921b3e439811cf5) -> tag name: option], [[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (c33ce4eedeef26cc3921b3e439811cf5)]  -> tag name: option]]

Comment: How are you finding the element? `driver.findElement(category);` where does the category comes from and what is its value?

Comment: By categories = By.xpath(".//*[@class='row m-b-1']/div[1]/select");

Comment: Your variable name in above is categories while in code you provided you are using category. Typo?

Comment: yes sorry it was a typo

Comment: After you found element, can you make sure its correct one? You can do something like `WebElement element = driver.findElement(category); String elementClass = element.getAttribute("class");` and output that class into console. Make sure its form-control. Basically make sure you are grabbing the correct element first. Second, find a way to list all the select options into console so you can make sure its proper select element you got.